# How to add 3D touch quick actions inside an app? Like in contacts

Tags: ios, 3dtouch, quickaction

Is there an API to show quick actions menu on force touch inside an app? I only see APIs for showing quick actions menu when you swipe-up peek view. But I want to do something like the example from apple 3D touch page.

Here is what I want to achieve
[3D touch quick actions menu on contacts on 6s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqm8u.png)

Comment: Hi nimish, how did you do this at the end? Would you mind providing some code? Thxs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be another solution but one of the I think is you can show this custom view on detection of 3D touch. You can do it from

- `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` method  `previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:` 
  or
  you can use `force` and `maximumPossibleForce` properties of `UITouch` to detect pressure applied on screen and show this custom view after particular pressure level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my own library [**ActionsList**](https://github.com/LowKostKustomz/ActionsList) which has the same look and feel as Apple's Quick Actions menu.

It **has not 3D Touch support yet**, but it can help you with presenting the same actions list as on the provider screenshot.

**First you should create list.**

If you want to present it from `UIButton`, `UIBarButtonItem` of `UITabBarItem` there is built-in methods for creating list:

```
// element is UIButton, UIBarButtonItem or UITabBarItem
let list = element.createActionsList()
```

Otherwise you should use `ActionsListModel` structure:

```
let list = ActionsListModel(senderView: viewThatInitiatedListPresenting,
                            sourceView: viewToPresentListFrom,
                            delegate: listDelegate)
```

**Then add actions to the list**

```
list.add(action: ActionsListDefaultButtonModel(localizedTitle: "Create Alarm", 
                 image: UIImage(named: "Alarm clock"),
                 action: { action in
                     // You can use action's list property to control it

                     // - To dismiss
                     action.list?.dismiss()

                     // - To update action appearance
                     action.appearance.//anything
                     // Do not forget to reload actions to apply changes
                     action.list?.reloadActions()
          }))
```

**After that you can present list**

```
list.present()

// Save list or it will be deallocated and not reachable outside of the scope it was created in
self.list = list
```

[image]